# Why does this makefile remove two .c files at the end?

Tags: python, c, makefile, cython

I have a Makefile that looks like this:

```
TARGET = Game
OBJ = Game.o BaseGame.o main.o

PFLAGS = -a
CFLAGS = -c -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -Wall -std=c11
LFLAGS = -lpython2.7
CC = gcc

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@

main.c:
    cython main.py $(PFLAGS) --embed

%.c: %.py
    cython $< $(PFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.c html/* $(TARGET)
```

When I run "make" on the terminal, this is the output:

```
cython Game.py -a
gcc Game.c -c -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -Wall -std=c11 -o Game.o
cython BaseGame.py -a
gcc BaseGame.c -c -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -Wall -std=c11 -o BaseGame.o
cython main.py -a --embed
gcc main.c -c -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -Wall -std=c11 -o main.o
gcc Game.o BaseGame.o main.o -lpython2.7 -o Game
rm Game.c BaseGame.c
```

My question is, why does the makefile delete Game.c and BaseGame.c when it's finished? The last command isn't even in the makefile!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to have `make` keep intermediate files (the .c files are intermediate files)

use the

```
.PRECIOUS: <list of file names>
```

in the makefile

the following is from https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html

.PRECIOUS

```
The targets which .PRECIOUS depends on are given the following special treatment: if make is killed or interrupted during the execution of their recipes, the target is not deleted. See Interrupting or Killing make. Also, if the target is an intermediate file, it will not be deleted after it is no longer needed, as is normally done. See Chains of Implicit Rules. In this latter respect it overlaps with the .SECONDARY special target.

You can also list the target pattern of an implicit rule (such as ‘%.o’) as a prerequisite file of the special target .PRECIOUS to preserve intermediate files created by rules whose target patterns match that file’s name.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed the "*.c" in the `clean` section?

```
clean:
    rm -f *.o *.c html/* $(TARGET)
```

Comment: Yeah, but if the makefile was running the clean section then it would remove everything, not just two seemingly random .c files.